Selenium downloads
We're using Selenium in Python 3.12 to work with Google Chrome via standard chromedriver. We've also utilized proxy mechanism through an extension that's loaded into Chrome, proxying only the needed URLs through.
The problem is that for some unknown reason, after pod has been launched, Chrome downloads a large chunk of data through proxy, even though the only thing we have there in code is just to launch the process, open about:blank tab and wait for incoming requests.

Above is the picture for network logs for the pod. What could Chrome / Selenium download at the beginning, while making use of proxy? Why does it use the proxy in the first place if it downloads some internal stuff (if that's what it is)? Proxy traffic ain't cheap, and if we scale it up it will eat the bandwidth very quickly.
What else we can check to get an idea what consumes so much traffic besides HAR files?
This is the code we use to create the driver:
    def create_driver(
        driver: str,
        browser_binary_path: str,
        driver_binary_path: str,
        user_data_dir: str = None,
        browser_data_dir: str = None,
        disk_cache_dir: str = None,
        id_number: int = 0

) -> webdriver.Chrome:
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    user_agent = fake_useragent.UserAgent().chrome
    options.add_argument(f"--user-agent={user_agent}")
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        if sock.connect_ex(('localhost', 9222 + id_number)) == 0:
            raise RuntimeError(f"Порт {9222 + id_number} уже занят.")
    options.add_argument(f'--remote-debugging-port={9222 + id_number}')
    options.add_extension(os.path.abspath('proxy_auth_plugin.crx'))
    if user_data_dir is not None:
        options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={user_data_dir}")
    if browser_data_dir is not None:
        options.add_argument(f"--data-path={browser_data_dir}")
    if disk_cache_dir is not None:
        options.add_argument(f"--disk-cache-dir={disk_cache_dir}")
    if browser_binary_path is not None:
        options.binary_location = browser_binary_path
    if driver == 'chrome':
        if driver_binary_path != '':
            service = ChromeService(executable_path=driver_binary_path)
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
        else:
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
        return driver

UPDATE
Starting to believe it has something to do with CRX extension - when I turn it being loaded, the usage at the beginning drops immediately. Of course, it also stops data flow through proxy provider, which is not needed, but at least the culprit seems to be with the extension.

